# Return blank if #VALUE is returned

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I've setup a formula that combines numbers from multiple worksheets and then compares it against another number from worksheet.

I am using the `INDIRECT` function to reference the sheets as well as `COLUMN` and `ROW` to adjust the numbers to the corresponding coordinates when I drag it across.

However, some of the figures don't always exist in the worksheets so a `#VALUE` error is returned. How Can I change it so a blank cell is shown if this happens?

My Current formula: `=INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!R"&ROW(E29)&"C"&COLUMN(E29),FALSE)-SUM(INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!R"&ROW(C29)&"C"&COLUMN(C29),FALSE),INDIRECT("'"&$C$13&"'!R"&ROW(E29)&"C"&COLUMN(E29),FALSE))`

Comment: I agree with @mehow.However a word of caution: `=IFERROR()` is available from `xl2007` onwards. For previous excel versions use `If(Iserror())`

Answer (score 3):

Use `=IFERROR(<your original formula>, "")` which will replace any error with `""` but passes any other result through.

But do bear in mind the degradation in spreadsheet stability: `INDIRECT` makes spreadsheets brittle enough on its own: your hiding any error output could be dangerous.

Comment: `"your hiding any error output could be dangerous"` +1 on this alone. Hiding errors from a manager / co-worker / stakeholder could be ruinous! Be wary with things like this.